# Salvar uma imagem e gerar Thumb com nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, thumbnail, imagemagick

estou tentando gravar uma imagem em disco e após isso gerar um thumb da imagems que foi salva.

Para fazer isso eu salvo normal a imagem em base64 que foi enviada e no callback do fs.writeFile eu chamo a função para gerar o thumb.

Estou tentando gerar o thumb utilizando o pacote [imagemagick](https://github.com/ImageMagick/ImageMagick)

```
const im = require('imagemagick');
const fs = require('fs');

const imagemCapa        = objetoFolder + "\\" + comando.imagemCapa;
const imagemCapaThumb   = objetoFolder + "\\capa_thumb.jpg";

//Grava no disco
fs.writeFile(imagemCapa, comando.imagemCapaBase64, 'base64', (err) => {
    if(err) console.log(err);

    //Thumb
    const optionsThumb = {
        srcPath: imagemCapa,
        dstPath: imagemCapaThumb,
        width: 262                                  
    };
    im.resize(optionsThumb, (err, stdout, stderr) => {
        if (err) console.log(err);
        console.log('Thumb gerado');
    });

});
```

Consigo gravar a imagem em disco mas não está gerando o thumb.

Quem puder ajudar agradeço de antemão! Um abraço.

Comment: Não devias usar `imagemCapa` em vêz de `capa.jpg`? Como está estás sempre à procura da mesma imagem e não daquela que foi gravada. Pode ser que tenhas problemas com pastas também, podes explicar em que pasta está o teu ficheiro `.js` e em que pasta a imagem é gravada?

Comment: Opa @Sergio, eu tinha colocado errado. Tem as variáveis que recebem o caminho da imagem que foi salva e do thumb antes, são as imagemCapa e imagemCapaThumb.

Comment: Recebes algum erro no Node?

Comment: Não recebo, esse é o problema... ele salva a imagem, entra no callback da geração do thumb mas não salva o thumb de fato.

Comment: No código que está na pergunta não tens nada que grave o thumbnail. Sabes disso ou é essa parte que não sabes como fazer?